# Add Properties to Asp.Net 2.0 Identity Database first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a DataBase First Website in mvc.

My Problem is that i want to add some Points to the AspNetUser and be able to show/modify them. For example when register.

So i added for example age to the AspNetUser updated the Database.  Then i went to the edmx DataBase and updated my Model so far so good. Everything is working till this point.

Now i went to the IdentityModel and added the age.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here            
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then i went to the RegisterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
.....

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i try to start the Website and to Login, as soon as i press Login i get the Folowing error.

The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

```
Zeile 77:             // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
Zeile 78:             // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
Zeile 79:             var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
Zeile 80:             switch (result)
Zeile 81:             {
```

As soon as i comment out the last two changes everything works again.I´m wondering what i`ve done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your project to work with the additional properties you need to add a "Migration" in order that Entity Framework Code First can update your database automatically-

1. Open the NuGet package manager console from the "Tools" menu in Visual Studio.
2. Type *"add-migration AddedUserProperties"*
3. Type *"update-database"*

See [Code First Migrations on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx) for more information.

Depending on your project configuration you may need to type "enable-migrations" which will set up code first migrations for you before this can work (if it is set up already you should have a "Migrations" directory in your project).

It is also possible to set your code first context to drop and recreate the database if the model has changed, or simply every time you run your code.

Obviously dropping the database is going to delete any users already registered, so this is probably best done in the early prototyping stage and with "DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges" initialization rather than "DropCreateDatabaseAlways", or by seeding your test users so that these are automatically recreated with the database.

To do this -

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

See [Understanding Database Initializers in Entity Framework Code First](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) for more.